# Exposing mutliple https ports in Dockerfile

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, port

Is there a way to EXPOSE two ports in one Dockerfile that work on https, my Dockerfile was created automatically by my dotnet core project and with it it came with port 80 for http and port 443 for https, is there a way to add more https ports?

Comment: What have you tried already, and what problems are you running into?  Can you edit the question to include the Dockerfile you have now?  `EXPOSE`ing more ports isn't hard, but also doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Its not a problem that I'm running into its just a question about EXPOSE, can I somehow specify that EXPOSE PORT_NUM, PORT_NUM will run on https, and not on http which is default

Comment: The `EXPOSE` syntax is the same for all TCP-based services.  You can't tell Docker that the byte stream is HTTP, HTTP/TLS, PostgreSQL, Redis, AMQP/0.9, or anything else; conversely, Docker never looks at the byte stream and it doesn't matter.